# How to change A record in DNS and keep email working when MX record point to the domain itself

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, domain, mx-record

For my client, I'm migrating domain to point to a new website server. In order to do that, I'm changing A records to point to new server IP. After such change, client has lost possibility to send e-mails from his mail accounts located on old server. DNS Configuration is as follows:

Domain name: example.com

| Host | Type | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| @ | A | XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX |
| www | A | XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX |
| @ | MX | 10 example.com |

After changing A records to YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY it seems like the MX records are now pointing to IP of new server, which does not have mail functionality, and that stops the e-mail from working. Can I somehow point the MX record towards the old server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your MX record currently points to the domain itself, that means it's essentially pointing to the @ DNS record. So when you update that the MX destination is changed.

Add an additional A record to the domain which points to the old server, for instance `mail.example.com`, and then point the MX record to that A record rather than the main ones that are being moved. So you end up with this.

| Host | Type | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| @ | A | YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY |
| www | A | YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY |
| mail | A | XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX |
| @ | MX | 10 mail.example.com |